# How to start a bat script with anaconda prompt instead of cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, anaconda, conda

I want to deliver an app that is based on anaconda. I can start the app with a bat file from the anaconda prompt. The problem is, that bat files are called with cmd.exe instead of anaconda prompt. After installing anaconda on windows the `conda` executable is generally not in the `PATH` variable. So, cmd.exe does not know how to `call activate condaenv`.
Is there a way to make the bat file start with anaconda prompt when clicking on it with the mouse?

I don't want to have to open the anaconda prompt and start the script from there.

Comment: Why did you start another question?

Comment: This question is addressing a specific aspect of the other question. The other question might have an answer which is not related to this problem. So, I opened another question, because it is another question. :-)

Comment: Why can I not mark and copy text in the cmd.exe?Arg.

Comment: If it's not in PATH why don't just add it to the PATH variable yourself? To copy just right click (or click the logo menu, or Alt+Space) > mark if you don't have quick edit mode enabled and then press `Enter` to copy

Comment: The average user does not even know what a PATH variable is.